# TypeScript type assertion from mixed object list

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to find an item in an array by it's custom type?

```
type A = {
  x: number;
};

type B = {
  y: number;
};

type Mixed = A | B;

const list: Mixed[] = [{x:5}, {y:3}];

const a = list.find(item => 'x' in item);  // <-- how to make something like this work?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
type A = {
    x: number;
  };
  
  type B = {
    y: number;
  };
  
  type Mixed = A | B;
  
  const list: Mixed[] = [{x:5}, {y:3}];
  
  const a = list.find(item => item.hasOwnProperty('x')) as A;
```

Comment: ah ha!  forgot the `as A`.  Thanks @Aadmaa

Comment: Please note that this is very dangerous, because `find` might not find anything but you are forcing TS to believe, that you will always find something and this will easily lead to runtime errors down the road.

Answer (score 0):

Jan isn't wrong. Here's a better answer, showing how to filter the mixed array into two typed lists - without the potential for a "undefined" value to be mistyped as A or B.

```
type A = {
    x: number;
};
  
type B = {
   y: number;
};
  
type Mixed = A | B;
  
const list: Mixed[] = [{x:5}, {y:3}];
  
const isA = (candidate: Mixed): candidate is A => {
      return (candidate && candidate.hasOwnProperty('x'))
  }

const isB = (candidate: Mixed): candidate is B => {
    return (candidate && candidate.hasOwnProperty('y'))
}

const AItems = list.filter(item => isA(item)) as A[];
const BItems = list.filter(item => isB(item)) as B[];
```